# Ruby 2.0 Breaking Change? Date Comparison

Tags: rspec, ruby-2.0

Heroku is saying that Ruby 2.0 is [ready for production](https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2013/6/17/ruby-2-default-new-aps). Okay, I'll update my app. But my tests break. This one started failing:

```
a_date.should == the_same_date
```

The dates are equal. How do I know, besides that the same test passes under Ruby 1.9.3?  This passes under 2.0:

```
a_date.to_i.should == the_same_date.to_i
```

Is this a bug in Ruby 2.0? I can't find anything about breaking changes to date equality.

**UPDATE**

Here is the actual test output:

```
Failure/Error: target.should == @now
  expected: Mon, 24 Jun 2013 15:40:52 UTC +00:00
  got:      Mon, 24 Jun 2013 15:40:52 UTC +00:00 (using ==)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with TimeCop; I think [this one](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop/issues/83). In any case, switching to the head version solved the problem.

The problem was caused by freezing the time as `Time.current`.  The two times were off by a single millisecond. Instead of comparing `#to_i` as I mention above, I should have compared `#to_f`.